# Divide a Spring MVC project into two parts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a fully working Spring MVC project. Now a requirement has come to create a new project within this project. 
Is there any easy way to divide the projects into two parts within my current project?

I want to separate the DAO files(Model), Controller files & View files (which are in separate folders), and still don't touch anything on the current project.
The current project has everything in packages.
The new project will use the same database.

Something like this is the wanted outcome:

```
> -Project 1 - Classes
> -Project 1 - DAO files/interfaces
> -Project 1 - Controller
> -Project 2 - Classes
> -Project 2 - DAO files/interfaces
> -Project 2 - Controller
```

Thanks in forehand

Comment: if your project is configured via Maven, put dao (and services) into a  new Maven project, leave all the rest in the former Maven project and add a dependency on the new project to pom.xml of the former project.

Comment: As @JohnDonn said, you can use modules for this. Maven, gradle, etc. help you in this task. Here an example with maven: https://github.com/agile-itsm/agile-itsm